# Understanding JWT and SSO

Tags: csrf, jwt, sso

I'm having trouble understanding how to set up SSO between my app and another app we have deployed. I'm new to trying to set this kind of thing up, so I was hoping someone could explain whether I'm on the right path, both from a standpoint of making it work as well as a standpoint of making it secure.

We have our app (let's say it's `https://app.mydomain.example`).

- Our users log in there with their user/pass.
- This app uses angular and webapi.
- The login endpoint makes use of `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`.

All of this was set up by our previous developer, so my knowledge about how it works isn't as much as I'd like.

Now we have a desire to allow our users to use Jupyter Notebook. Let's say we have this set up at `https://jupyter.mydomain.example`. And, since they are already logged into our app, we don't want them to have to log in again to Jupyter.

One of our AWS guys set the Jupyter side up using [jwtauthenticator](https://github.com/mogthesprog/jwtauthenticator). His initial request was that I code our app to do the following:

1. Generate a JWT token in our app.
2. Add a link in the app which would open `jupyter.mydomain.example` in a new tab.
3. Pass an `Authorization: bearer <jwttoken>` header when this link is clicked.

He tested sending this header in PostMan successfully. However, on the app side, I don't believe it's possible to tell the browser to send headers when opening in a new tab, so that solution won't work.

Next suggestion from our AWS guy decided to set it up using query parameters. Basically something like:

`https://jupyter.mydomain.example?jwt=<jwt token>`

This also worked for him in PostMan and I'm pretty sure it would work in the app. But isn't this a security risk, even with HTTPS? I believe at the very least, the token goes into the server logs which I don't think is a great idea.

The query parameter idea made me think about using POST, as I believe the token would be encrypted at that point. But, even if I'm correct, it appears jwtauthenticator won't handle POST requests. I suppose it could be modified to handle them, but I'm not sure that's the right solution.

After reviewing jwtauthenticator code, it would appear that it also will look for a cookie named XSRF-TOKEN. This is what I **think** is the appropriate solution, but I'm not sure. Plus, I can't seem to make it work.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. User clicks link which hits an endpoint (let's say api/auth/jupyter)
2. Endpoint generates JWT token
3. Endpoint sets cookie.

   - Name is XSRF-TOKEN.
   - Value is the JWT token string.
   - Secure is true
   - HttpOnly is false
   - Domain is `mydomain.example`
   - Path is `/`
4. OK response with cookie is returned to client (DevTools for `app.mydomain.example` shows the cookie is set).
5. Call `window.open("https://jupyter.mydomain.example")` (DevTools for `jupyter.mydomain.example` also shows the cookie is set).

Unfortunately I'm getting a 401 error. I've also tried setting this cookie in PostMan and testing that way, which also responds with a 401. Judging from the jwtauthenticator code, I think the only thing that could be happening is that the cookie is not being read.

So, I guess I have a few questions:

1. Is there some security reason that would be keeping the cookie from being read? I assumed since they are on the same domain that wouldn't be the problem.
2. Assuming I can get the problem with reading the cookie figured out, is this secure? I'm concerned there's still a CSRF problem.
3. In general, is this an appropriate way to provide SSO? Or are we going down the wrong path? I know security is not always easy, but both our AWS guy and I have put in a lot of time trying to come up with a solution. It seems easy. All we have to do is get the token to the Jupyter server. But this is proving very difficult, which makes me think we're doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Shouldn't the domain on the cookie bet set to `.mydomain.com` (prepend .) to allow other subdomains access?

Comment: I've read that it's no longer needed. And it seems something along the way did that automatically, as DevTools does show a period.

Comment: what about cookie expiration? i didn't see that you included that

Comment: None specified, which according to DevTools appears to mean it will expire in 2038.

Comment: This seems incorrect; the CSRF cookie should have nothing to do with authentication. Also, the cookie has to be set at the mydomain.com level if you are sharing cookies across sites.

Comment: So, are you saying the XSRF-TOKEN handling code in jwtauthenticator makes no sense? For reference, it's here: https://github.com/mogthesprog/jwtauthenticator/blob/master/jwtauthenticator/jwtauthenticator.py

Comment: As posted earlier, the cookie has domain of mydomain.com, so I think that's good.